# Is it posible create a selection field dynamiclly?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-16

```
vt_invoice_type_dinamic = fields.Selection([
('1', 'Sale'),
('2', 'Education'),
('14', 'Services'),
('22', 'Invoice WA'),
], string='Siat invoice type')
```

Actually I have this field with four values for selection, I need to display 1 and 2, depending of an boolean field that is called vt_flag.

```
vt_flag = fields.Boolean(string='Flag for dynamic invoice', default=False)
```

If the field is True I need to display only 1 and 2 values, and if is False display all the values
My question is.. Is it posible? How can I do that?

Comment: Use a Many2one field instead.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```py
vt_invoice_type_dinamic = fields.Selection(selection='select_filter', string='Siat invoice type')

@api.model
def select_filter:
    if self.vt_flag:
        return ([('1', 'Sale'),('2', 'Education')])
    else:
        return ([('14', 'Services'),('22', 'Invoice WA')])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).